# Sum of specific values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sum, rows, multiple-columns

I'm trying to find the sum of specific values within a table, using SQL. A sample table is:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  ID   |  Co1  |  Va1  |  Co2  |  Va2  |  Co3  |  Va3  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  01   |  AA1  |   23.0|  AA2  |   11.2|  AA3  | 328.34|
|  02   |  AA2  |   27.0|  AA3  | 234.56|  AA4  |   23.8|
|  03   |  AA1  | 409.01|  AA4  | 234.98| NULL  | NULL  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I have 35 such 'Code' columns and values.

What I need is selecting a table having only one code. Say I need Code AA3, this would be (the Code column is not required here, but only to show where I got the values):

```
+-------+-------+--------+
|  ID   | Code  |  Value |
+-------+-------+--------+
|  01   |  AA3  |  328.34|
|  02   |  AA3  |  234.56|
|  03   |  AA3  |       0|
+-------+-------+--------+
```

And I will later need another (separate) query which contains the sum of several codes, for example the sum of codes AA1 and AA2 together.

```
+-------+---------+
|  ID   |   Value |
+-------+---------+
|  01   |     34.2|
|  02   |     27.0|
|  03   |   409.01|
+-------+---------+
```

I was thinking about having a 'WHERE' and run on every 35 columns, but that would really be tedious and this does not seem too efficient. I was wondering if there was a way to do that through SQL (I can do it with Excel with an if statement and it works wonders).

Maybe if there was a way to 'search' through a row, return the column name and then use that column name to retrieve the number?

Let me know if you require more information =)

Comment: Which RDMBS are you using, SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL? At the first sentece you say "Using SQL", you mean MS SQL Server? On last question, do you have only 3 code columns? The SUM will be only for AA1 and AA2 or more combinations?

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. It's SQL Server 2008R2 that I'm using.

Comment: For some reason, I didn't see your other comment... oh well. Yes, there are actually 35 code columns and 35 amount columns. The codes vary from AA1 to AA652. And for the second part (adding several codes), I need to add 9 codes: AA74, AA76, AA78 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is **store your data in a normalised form**.

However...

```
select SUM(v)
from
(

select * -- ID, r, v 
from 
(select * from yourtable) u
unpivot
( r for co in (co1, co2, co3)) as u1
unpivot
(  v for va in (va1, va2, va3)) as u2
where RIGHT(co,1) = RIGHT(va,1)
) v
WHERE R = 'AA1' -- etc
```

will return the results you seek

Comment: I wish it was normalized! >.< It would be much more simple that way.

Hmm, could you explain it a bit for me? I'm quite new to SQL (^^;)

For instance, the 'FOR' does a loop? And I'm not sure why you took the left character from the right in the 'value' in the WHERE statement...

Comment: UNPIVOT takes a denormalised table like yours, and normalises it (ie: makes it more vertical and less horizontal). However it can only do one datatype, so you need to do it twice to get both types out. The RIGHT matches the last character of the text data (CO1, CO2) to the last character of the value data (VA1, VA2). Try replacing the SUM(V) with * to see the whole data set

Comment: Ah! I thought that you were taking the values in the column value and taking the last character! By selecting everything I now understand that it's actually the column name that you are matching. Thanks! That works! :D (except the column data types I imported in SQL server didn't match... oh well, I'll have to re-import them properly)

Comment: @Unknown008: If you imported the data yourself, couldn't you normalize it as well in that step? Might save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice your comment until now, sorry for the late reply. And no, I was provided the data like that. I hope I won't get more data like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure is less than ideal.  I'll show you a straight forward example similar to your Excel based `IF` method, and then a much simpler query with a normalised data-structure.

```
SELECT
  id,
    CASE WHEN co1 = 'AA1' THEN co1 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN co2 = 'AA1' THEN co2 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN co3 = 'AA1' THEN co3 ELSE 0 END
  + CASE WHEN co4 = 'AA1' THEN co4 ELSE 0 END
  + etc, etc
FROM
  yourTable
```

With 30 codes per `id`, you need 30 `CASE` statements.

The alternative is to have several rows of data per `id`, instead of several columns per `id`.

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  ID   |  Obs  |  Cod  |  Val  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  01   |   1   |  AA1  |  23.0 |
|  01   |   2   |  AA2  |  11.2 |
|  01   |   3   |  AA3  | 328.34|
|  02   |   1   |  AA2  |   27.0|
|  02   |   2   |  AA3  | 234.56|
|  02   |   3   |  AA4  |   23.8|
|  03   |   1   |  AA1  | 409.01|
|  03   |   2   |  AA4  | 234.98|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The the query is simple, you can add as many observations as you like without changing the table structure, and a whole host of other advantages...

```
 Query if one id can have several           Query if one id can only have one
 observations for the same code:            observation for any one code:
----------------------------------         -----------------------------------
 SELECT                                     SELECT
   id,                                        *
   cod,                                     FROM
   SUM(val)   AS val                          yourTable 
 FROM                                       WHERE
   yourTable                                  cod = 'AA1'
 WHERE
   cod = 'AA1'
 GROUP BY
   id,
   cod
```

Comment: Yea, that's why I wasn't too keen on having 35 WHERE statements, haha x3

But no, I wouldn't be able to sort it like that, especially with several thousands of records =(

Thanks for your answer all the same =)

Comment: @Unknown008 - Be aware, however, that SQL is not intended for your type of table structure. You either need to pre-process your data (see the `pivot` answer to your question) *[potentially large processing overheads every execution]*, normalise your data to one suitable to RDBMS/SQL *[significant investing to refactor your data]*, or have highly redundant code *[potentially large coding and maintenance overheads]*. Sorry, it seems that you have a legacy problem (the data structure) that forces you into a corner where there are no 'ideal' approaches.

Comment: @Unknown008 - Also, do note that there are many ways to normailise your data quite quickly.  Several thousand records isn't actually very many.

Comment: I see, thanks for the comments Dems =) We are actually requesting data to be more ordered for next time; having one column for each code and this should make things easier with a simple `SELECT SUM(column) FROM table GROUP BY id`. I guess we'll stick to the excel this time.