# Manipulating complex data

Tags: excel, ms-access

I want to produce a table that presents/analyses my data in this format:
             Value by Month

```
ID     Jan 09  Feb 09  Mar 09  Apr 09  May 09  Jun 09 Jul 09
1234   10      0       0       0       5       10       8 
2345   0       0       0       0       7        0       5
3456   5       0       0       7       0        0       3
```

I've been given data in the following format (month in first column followed by value in second column) where any months missing are '0'. Any ideas how I can manipulate this in MS Access or Excel?

```
ID
1234  01-01-2009 10    01-06-2009 20    01-07-2009 15
2345  01-02-2009 15    01-04-2009 20    01-06-2009 10    01-07-2009 16
3456  01-03-2009 8     01-04-2009 30    01-07-2009 4
```

The data runs by month for six years and so is quite complicated to do manually.

Comment: Sorry, that formatting didn't work in that what I can see here isn't how I laid it out in when writing the question - I can email pictures of how the data is actually formatted vs how I would like it to be if you can provide an email address.

Comment: Post a picture of the data to imgur or somewhere and add the link to the post.  Someone will edit it in since you don't have the rep for an image... although the edits by Jonathon make it decent.  You might [take a look at that edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30580394/revisions) to see how to do that in the future.

Comment: Thanks - actually (and I assume somebody has done this, so thanks) it's now showing as I'd like it to, so this is all now present and correct.

Comment: Do you have access to an SQL engine? Not MS Access as it is not powerful enough. I actually had a [quite similar question way while back](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11825158/1578604), and you should be able to use part of the SQL to get a step from your result, then take that to Excel where a simple pivot would finish things off. I can modify the query and add the last piece to get your required format if you want.

Comment: Sorry pnuts, the data in the two examples above don't match up. I retyped a couple of simple examples to make formatting here easier. using the second table, the result for id 3456 and date Jan 09 would be 8.

Comment: Hi Jerry - I don't currently have an SQL engine, but I could get one. I'll take a look at your 'similar question'. If you were able to modify the query as you've suggested, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Is your data in Access or in Excel?

Comment: It came in Excel, but I've inputted to Access as well.

Comment: In all honesty, I would flatten the file then drop a pivot table on top of it. The quick way to flatten the file is simply copy and paste, you could flatten that in about 30 seconds. Let me know if you want to do this and you get stuck and I will post an answer as it allows more chars than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I propose, which uses SQL if you can get to use one. I usually use MS SQL Server 2008R2, so the queries I will be using in this answer will work there, whilst I cannot guarantee it working on a different SQL engine.

First, I have created the table and using the data you have in your question, I have this:

[image]

Here we have a database called 'SO', in which there's a table named 'dbo.Test' and with the columns and data types described. nvarchar(10) means that the columns contain text-based values of maximum length 10. null at the end indicates that there can also be null values (similar to blank values) in the columns.

So what I did that was not in the question was give some headers, the first column being 'ID' and all the subsequent ones alternating 'DaX' and 'VaX' (X representing a number, and 'Da' to mean dates and 'Va' to mean values'). Note that it is actually better to import the values as numeric (I forgot to import them as such and decided to leave it as such to show that it can be fine even this way).

So the query below is quite advanced (at least to my eyes) since it builds up a query from variables and I myself had to look quite a bit around to get the syntax right and the code working. To run it, you need to create a new query, paste the below and execute the code.

```sql
-- Use the database named SO
USE SO

-- Create some variables
DECLARE @Script  VARCHAR(MAX), -- The variable to hold the final script
        @Dates   VARCHAR(MAX), -- This will hold the column names of date columns
        @Values  VARCHAR(MAX)  -- This will hold the column names of value columns      

-- This is a temporary table holding the column number and column
-- names for date columns.
;WITH [Cols] AS (
    -- Get column number and column names from sys.table
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS [RowID],
        [name]
    FROM
        sys.columns
    -- Where the object is the data table called Test
    WHERE
        [object_id] = object_id('Test')
    -- And where the column name begins with 'da' (case insensitive)
    AND
        [name] LIKE 'da%'
),
-- Another temporary table that uses the above to make a comma 
-- separated list of all date column names. It uses recursion to do that
[Concted] AS (
    -- Get the first column number and name from the above temp table
    SELECT
        [RowID],
        CAST([name] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [name]
    FROM
        [Cols]
    WHERE
        [RowID] = 1
    -- Add it to...
    UNION ALL
    -- The current column name, a comma and another column name
    SELECT
        [Cols].[RowID],
        CAST([Concted].[name] + ',' + [Cols].[name] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM
        [Concted]
    JOIN
        [Cols]
    -- That other column name determined by taking the current row number and the next
    ON
        [Cols].[RowID] = [Concted].[RowID] + 1
)
-- Get the first row from the second temp table (which now contains all
-- dates separated by comma and store in @Dates
SELECT 
    @Dates = [name]
FROM
    [Concted]
WHERE
    [RowID] = (SELECT MAX([RowID]) FROM Concted)


-- Do the same for values
;WITH [Cols] AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS [RowID],
        [name]
    FROM
        sys.columns
    WHERE
        [object_id] = object_id('Test')
    AND
        [name] LIKE 'va%'
),
[Concted] AS (
    SELECT
        [RowID],
        CAST([name] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [name]
    FROM
        [Cols]
    WHERE
        [RowID] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        [Cols].[RowID],
        CAST([Concted].[name] + ',' + [Cols].[name] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM
        [Concted]
    JOIN
        [Cols]
    ON
        [Cols].[RowID] = [Concted].[RowID] + 1
)
SELECT 
    @Values = [name]
FROM
    [Concted]
WHERE
    [RowID] = (SELECT MAX([RowID]) FROM Concted)


-- Here we build the 'skeleton' of the main script, and it uses the two 
-- lists of columns we built earlier above.
SET @Script = '
    -- Select the ID, dates and values
    SELECT
        [ID],
        [Dates],
        [Values]
    FROM
        Test
    -- Unpivot once on dates
    UNPIVOT (
        [Dates] FOR [Date] IN ('+@Dates+')
    ) AS u1
    -- Unpivot a second one for values
    UNPIVOT (
        [Values] FOR [Value] IN ('+@Values+')
    ) AS u2
    -- Where the column number for date and value match and 
    -- neither dates nor values are blanks
    WHERE
        SUBSTRING([Date],3,LEN([Date])) = SUBSTRING([Value],3,LEN([Value]))
    AND
        ISNULL([Dates],'''') <> ''''
    AND
        ISNULL([Values],'''') <> ''''
'
-- Execute the above script
EXEC (@Script)
```

I explained as much as I can in the code with comments (lines beginning with `--`). Once run, I get the following from the above:

```
ID      Dates       Values
1234    01/01/2009  10
1234    01/06/2009  20
1234    01/07/2009  15
2345    01/02/2009  15
2345    01/04/2009  20
2345    01/06/2009  10
2345    01/07/2009  16
3456    01/03/2009  8
3456    01/04/2009  30
3456    01/07/2009  4
```

Once we have the above table, we can copy/paste it in excel to run a pivot and after a couple of clicks, we can get:

[image]